# Upgrade to Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I login to my Facebbok App page I see:
"Upgrade to Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS
This app uses an outdated version of the Facebook SDK for iOS. Please upgrade to the newest version."

I've just upgraded to the 3.1 SDK for my app, but my question is, when will this "warning" disappear? Will it be there as long there is any user out there using a version of my iOS app with the older facebook SDK?

Comment: Have you find the solution for this?. I am also facing the same problem here. If you find, please share the solution with me.

Comment: This is a bug. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and file a ticket so it can be resolved.